# Cannot have both the text and the child element 'LineBreak' within a property element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I have the following XAML:

```
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="15">
        line1<LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
        line2
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="ShowText">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

However Visual Studio throws the error

`Cannot have both the text 'line1' and the child element 'LineBreak' within a property element.`

And I don't know how to keep the line breaks and also fix the issue. I tried this:

```
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="15">
        <TextBlock.Text>
        line1<LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
        line2
        </TextBlock.Text>
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="ShowText">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
```

But then got the repeating error "Text property set more than once".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the Inlines behind the Style:

```
<TextBlock ...>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        ...
    </TextBlock.Style>
    line1<LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
    line2
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or wrap text with `<Run>`

```xml
<TextBlock ...>
    <Run>line1</Run>
    <LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
    <Run>line2</Run>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            ...
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Both this and Clemens' answers are very good, but I'll accept his, because it was first. Thank you, though!